# Check if array index is out of range in Dr Memory

Tags: c, gcc, memory-leaks, dr-memory

I need to check if an array index is out of range by using `Dr.Memory`. I don't use dynamic memory allocation in this case.

When I check this code with `Dr.Memory`. I'm using Windows 11.

```
int main() {
    clock_t start, end;
    float cpu_time_used;
    start = clock();

    int array[5] = {2, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int number = array[10];
    printf("This is a number: %i\n", number);

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((float) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nTotal speed  was %f\n", cpu_time_used);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get this output from `Dr.Memory`. As you can see, no complaining about that the index is out of range. Why?

```
Dr. Memory version 2.5.0 build 0 built on Oct 18 2021 03:01:22
Windows version: WinVer=105;Rel=2009;Build=22000;Edition=Professional
Dr. Memory results for pid 9640: "CControl.exe"
Application cmdline: ""C:\Users\dmn\OneDrive - ITH\Dokument\Projekt\Eclipse\CControl\Debug\CControl.exe""
Recorded 124 suppression(s) from default C:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory\bin64\suppress-default.txt

Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS beyond top of stack: reading 0x000000164a9ff980-0x000000164a9ff988 8 byte(s)
# 0 ___chkstk_ms                            [../../../../../src/gcc-11.2.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:132]
# 1 _pei386_runtime_relocator
# 2 __tmainCRTStartup
# 3 .l_start    
# 4 ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart
Note: @0:00:00.097 in thread 18604
Note: 0x000000164a9ff980 refers to 664 byte(s) beyond the top of the stack 0x000000164a9ffc18
Note: instruction: or     $0x0000000000000000 (%rcx) -> (%rcx)

Error #2: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS beyond top of stack: reading 0x000000164a9ffa50-0x000000164a9ffa58 8 byte(s)
# 0 ___chkstk_ms                       [../../../../../src/gcc-11.2.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:132]
# 1 __pformat_int.isra.0               [../../../../../src/gcc-11.2.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:138]
# 2 __mingw_pformat                    [../../../../../src/gcc-11.2.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:138]
# 3 __mingw_vfprintf                   [../../../../../src/gcc-11.2.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:138]
# 4 printf      
# 5 main        
Note: @0:00:00.135 in thread 18604
Note: 0x000000164a9ffa50 refers to 8 byte(s) beyond the top of the stack 0x000000164a9ffa58
Note: instruction: or     $0x0000000000000000 (%rcx) -> (%rcx)

Error #3: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading register rcx
# 0 __pformat_int.isra.0               [../../../../../src/gcc-11.2.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:138]
# 1 __mingw_pformat                    [../../../../../src/gcc-11.2.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:138]
# 2 __mingw_vfprintf                   [../../../../../src/gcc-11.2.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:138]
# 3 printf      
# 4 main        
Note: @0:00:00.135 in thread 18604
Note: instruction: test   %rcx %rcx

Error #4: POSSIBLE LEAK 98 direct bytes 0x00000153bd9001c0-0x00000153bd900222 + 0 indirect bytes
# 0 replace_malloc                   [d:\a\drmemory\drmemory\common\alloc_replace.c:2580]
# 1 msvcrt.dll!malloc_crt
# 2 msvcrt.dll!_setargv  
# 3 msvcrt.dll!_getmainargs
# 4 pre_cpp_init
# 5 msvcrt.dll!initterm  
# 6 __tmainCRTStartup
# 7 .l_start    
# 8 ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart

===========================================================================
FINAL SUMMARY:

DUPLICATE ERROR COUNTS:
    Error #   1:      2
    Error #   2:      2

SUPPRESSIONS USED:

ERRORS FOUND:
      2 unique,     4 total unaddressable access(es)
      1 unique,     1 total uninitialized access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
      0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of leak(s)
      1 unique,     1 total,     98 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
ERRORS IGNORED:
      3 unique,     3 total,    113 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
         (re-run with "-show_reachable" for details)
Details: C:\Users\dmn\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-CControl.exe.9640.000\results.txt
```

Comment: I never used this tool, but looks to me that it is complaining about a bunch of "unadressable accesses"

Comment: @EugeneSh. Do you recommend another tool? I don't like this tool either.

Comment: Perhaps the out-of-bound access is in the *total unaddressable access(es)* category which is showing that you have 4 of them. Btw. there is C or C++, no such language as C/C++, C **is not** a subset of C++.

Comment: @Pablo If I write nothing. then error `Error #3:` will not be shown.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that.

Comment: @Pablo If I only have an empty `int main() {return 0;}` function, then `Error #3:` from the list above, will not be shown.

Comment: Does mingw support address sanitizer?

Comment: @PaulSanders I don't think so.

Comment: Could try it `-fsanitize=address`

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you. It did not work. I tried Valgrind and now I can see that my C code has no errors. Dr.Memory is bad.